# Table pagination in angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular, pagination

I have been trying to implement table pagination for my html table in angular 2 but it doesn't work out for me. I have although included the scripts in my angular-cli.json file. What am i not doing right?

```
  <script>

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#foodTable').DataTable();
            } );


        </script>

        <script src="../foodlist/js/pagination1.js"></script>
        <script src="../foodlist/js/pagination2.js"></script>
        <script src="../foodlist/js/pagination3.js"></script>

<table  class="table" id="foodTable"  >
</table>
```

Comment: why are you using jquery inside?

Comment: @Aravind must i create a file for it too?

Comment: using jquery is not advisable you have a lot of plugins. What is the requirement is all about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should't use jQuery or load any any those JavaScript files.
You can do all of this with angular itself there are a lot great modules for pagination out there with great documentation.

http://valor-software.com/ng2-table/

http://michaelbromley.github.io/ng2-pagination/#/

These two are used in a lot of applications and have great documentation.